# How can I optimize python code: Euler projec prob 4

Tags: python

I've been working on  [Euler project problem 4](http://projecteuler.net/problem=4), my code works fine but it takes too much time (0.41 seconds).How can I optimize it so that it would take less time.Is there a trick I'm missing, or special functions that I'm not aware of?
This is the code:

```
#Note: tpal is a function to test if number is palindrome

pal =0

for i in range(999,100,-1):
    if pal >= i*999:    #A way to get out of loop and to not test on all numbers
        break 
    for j in range(999,100,-1):
        if pal >= i*999:
            break 
        if j > i:                         #numbers would already have been tested so I skip them 
            continue
        pot=i*j
        if ((tpal(pot)==1)and(pot> pal)):
            pal=pot
            i1=i
            j1=j

print(i1,j1,pal)

def tpal(num):
    num=list(str(num))
    Le=len(num)
    if Le == 1: # if number is of one digit than palindrome
        return 1

    le=len(num)

    if le%2 !=0: #4 example 10101even nbr
        le-=1
    le/2    

    for i in range(0,le):
       if num[i]!=num[Le-i-1]:
           return 0

    return 1
```

Comment: At the very least, you can start the inner loop with j = i.

Comment: 31 seconds?  Something is very, very wrong.  Your code takes 0.1s for me, and even a completely unoptimized 1-liner only took 0.8s.  What does your `tpal` function look like?

Comment: @DSM: Yea I got the same result

Comment: @DSM when I wrote the code on stack, I left out parts which prints stuff so that I can debug (for ex: print(i)). Apparently that was causing it to take so much time. I'm terribly sorry didn't know that printing causes that much damage. However DSM and A. R. S you said that it only took 0.1s it takes 0.4 with me. Is there any way to optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that it turns out the code has < 1 s runtime, it's not really that interesting any more.  You could modify the code to test fewer numbers and give up sooner.  But there's one obvious optimization which is kind of cute.  This line:

```
        if ((tpal(pot)==1)and(pot> pal)):
```

checks whether something is a palindrome each time, even if `pot <= pal`.  The palindrome test is expensive.  If you simply swap the order: (note you don't need the `==1`):

```
        if (pot > pal) and tpal(pot):
```

then you could save a lot of time:

```
In [24]: timeit orig()
1 loops, best of 3: 201 ms per loop

In [25]: timeit orig_swapped()
10 loops, best of 3: 30.1 ms per loop
```

because `A and B` doesn't evaluate B if `A` is already false and so it knows that `A and B` has to be false.  (This is called 'short-circuiting'; the same thing happens with 'A or B' if `A` is true.)

Incidentally, the last line here:

```
if le%2 !=0: #4 example 10101even nbr
    le-=1
le/2    
^^^^
```

doesn't change `le`.  I think these three lines are meant to amount to `le //= 2`.

Comment: Oh neat idea; it's pretty amazing how much faster a piece of code can become just by swapping two simple things.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it shouldn't take nearly as long as 31 seconds:

```
def isPalindrome(n):
    return str(n) == str(n)[::-1]

def listNums():
    a, b, pal = 0, 0, 0;
    for i in range(999, 99, -1):
        for j in range(999, 99, -1):
            n = i * j
            if isPalindrome(n) and n > pal:  # better to use "n > pal and isPalindrome(n)" instead, see other answer for details.
                a, b, pal = i, j, n
    return a, b, pal             

print listNums()
```

Running this should take around 1 second. For something like this you certainly don't need those superfluous `if` statements in your loop - if you loop through, say, `range(9999, 999, -1)`, you might consider making some optimizations like that (of course, there are a multitude of potential optimizations that could be made to something like this, e.g. not looping through every i,j pair twice).

Answer (score 0):

without giving you the whole answer. Here are some pointer.

- Reconsider your for loops, they are way to complicated. Maybe the inner loop should start at `i`?
- Remove all those silly if sentences, you don't need them if you for loops are correct.
- Finally, `int(str(pot)[::-1])==pot` then its a palindrome

EDIT:
Let the guy/girl solve the problem him/her self. No need in posting the solution here.